# Do I lose two levels just for choosing to fight King Tut?

Tags: munchkin

I am really new to Munchkin and I had a question about a card.

The King Tut card says "Will not pursue anyone of Level 3 or below. Higher-Leveled characters lose 2 levels, even if they escape."

Does this mean that as soon as combat starts with King Tut the player loses 2 levels?  What if someone joins in the fight, do they lose 2 levels as well?  And what if someone plays a card that cancels the combat (for example switches the monster)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, the loss of 2 levels is part of the bad stuff that happens when you normally fail to escape, or since the card specifically states it, "even if they escape." From the [World if Munchkin FAQ](http://www.worldofmunchkin.com/faq/),

> Q. King Tut and the Wight Brothers say "Characters of higher Levels [than 3] lose 2 levels, even if they escape." Does that mean you lose two levels even if you defeat those monsters?
>
> A. No. But if you cannot defeat them, then you must try to run away, and you'll lose the 2 levels even if you do escape. If they catch you, of course, you do suffer the Bad Stuff from those Monsters. (But you don't lose the two levels twice!)

Comment: That is confusing... They should label it "Running Away:" then like they do the Bad Stuff.

Thanks for the link to the FAQ with the official rule on the card.